# Android: MATCH_PARENT vs FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Tags: android, view

What's the difference between `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and `LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`? while both give same result!

`ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`:

[image: match_parent]

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`:

[image: fullscreen]

**Example:**

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN));
```

Comment: but those are not even used in the same places. how are you comparing them?

Comment: What?! I can use them in same place: `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` and BOTH works fine. ADDED EXAMPLE

Comment: yeah, obviously. the parameter is an int. You could put 42, it would "work", too, but it would not make any more sense. read the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog(android.content.Context, int)) for details on the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`MATCH_PARENT` is used to fill the parent.

And `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` is used to make full screen Window. (Hide statusbar )

Comment: Pawneshwer is right. One thing noticeable in your code is that you are trying to fullscreen a Dialog. Android's window manager has the last say on whether you are allowed to do that. Try doing a fullscreen on an activity instead by getting an instance of an WINDOW_SERVICE.